# Characters, centralizers and cosets

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, characters

I am trying to understand/count the number of solutions of a number of equations in finite groups and came across the following class function:

$$ \theta_\chi(x) = \sum_{y\in G} |C_G(xy)y \cap C_G(x)| \chi([y,x]) $$

where $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$.

Calculating its values seems to be a delicate task as one has to understand very well the centralizers of $G$, their cosets and their intersections.

**Two questions:

1. Has any one seen/studied this formula or a similar one?
2. Any idea/suggestion about how to simplify this expression?**

The function $\theta_\chi$ can be used to calculate the coefficients of the class function

$$f_3(g) = |\{(x,y,z)\in G^3 : [x,y]=[x,z]=[y,z]=g \}|$$

as a linear combination of the irreducible character of $G$. More precisely, if we let

$$ m_\chi = \sum_{x\in G} \theta_\chi(x) $$

then

$$f_3(g) = \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{m_\chi}{|G|}\chi(g) $$.

Comment: Is $C_G$ the centraliser or the conjugacy class?

Comment: Also, could you say anything further about how this arose?  It looks like an interesting expression, but I can't guess how one would arrive at it.

Comment: @LSpice: In this case, $C_{G}(x)$  means the centralizer of $x$.

Comment: @LSpice Just added more info about the context.